# How to run Tests in Groovy

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I have created some JUnit tests for a Groovy class but having trouble running them via Eclipse. Is it possible to run the Test in Eclipse, or is there a better way to run them?

Comment: Are the tests java classes or groovy scripts?

Comment: Groovy scripts then extend GroovyTestCase.

Comment: Have you checked the classpath configuration yet?

Answer (score -2):

You should create a test suite and register these test case classes. An example is shown here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Unit+Testing#UnitTesting-RunningaTestSuitecontainingGroovyTestCasescriptsdirectlyinEclipse

Comment: I tried that but it complains it cant find the TestSuite  'Class not found my.package.MyGroovyTestSuite'

Comment: Sounds like your working directory is wrong...  Are you using Gradle?  There is an eclipse target (via plugin 'eclipse') that will generate an eclipse project with all it's dependencies.

Comment: So obviously it is a classpath configuration issues. Are all your classes (including test classes) in the same source folder? Are you using a build framework, such as Maven or Gradle, and its project folde structure?

Comment: Why is this response voted down? It lead to new findings (classnotfound exception) which is not mentioned in the original question. Please justify your choice!

Comment: I didn't mark you down. I set Maven but it is not running the tests 'Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0'